# Rewarded Video Ad Exception

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I was testing out the Rewarded Video Ad functions , it seems to be working fine until i got an exception, the video ad seems to show up great but sometimes it is not showing at all ! The Video Ad is loaded and the

> onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad

Is not triggered at all, here is the exception :

```
07-21 20:48:31.710 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-21 20:48:31.710 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
07-21 20:48:32.320 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
07-21 20:49:16.360 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp W/Ads: Could not show rewarded video ad from adapter.
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bo ib.a' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.google.ads.mediation.AbstractAdViewAdapter.showVideo(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:228)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.u.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:193)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:29)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:16)
                                                                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznr$zza$zza.show(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznz.show(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at ma.altaiir.testapp.RewardedVideoAdHelper.show(RewardedVideoAdHelper.java:63)
                                                                      at ma.altaiir.testapp.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:526)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-21 20:49:16.360 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp W/Ads: Could not call showVideo.
                                                                  android.os.RemoteException
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.u.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:197)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:29)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:16)
                                                                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznr$zza$zza.show(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznz.show(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at ma.altaiir.testapp.RewardedVideoAdHelper.show(RewardedVideoAdHelper.java:63)
                                                                      at ma.altaiir.testapp.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:526)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-21 20:49:22.040 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-21 20:49:22.040 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
07-21 20:49:23.130 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp W/Ads: The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
07-21 20:49:23.375 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
07-21 20:49:23.410 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
07-21 20:50:23.405 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-21 20:50:23.405 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
07-21 20:50:23.970 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp W/Ads: The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
07-21 20:50:24.160 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
07-21 20:50:24.185 26818-26818/ma.altaiir.testapp I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```